# Connect Azure SQL Server using Service Principal ID in Python

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-sql-server, azure-service-principal

I am able to connect Azure SQL server using Connection String in python.
But I want to use service principle id to connect Azure SQL server.

Can anyone please guide me step by step, how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-azure-ad-service-principals-connect-sql-from-python-andrade) it says, You need

> Service Principals
> Granting Access to the Database
> Retrieving an AccessToken from Azure AD

A Service Principal is required to enable AAD authentication on the Azure SQL Server.
Including code to obtain an authentication token for database access.

[# Databricks: Connect to Azure SQL with Service Principal](https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal)

***References:***
[How to connect Azure SQL database from Python Function App using managed identity or access token](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-connect-azure-sql-database-from-python-function-app-using/ba-p/3035595)

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database